# I input an integer into a function expecting an integer out, I receive "None" as output

Tags: python, recursion

This program checks if a function is truly random by having a 50% chance for each outcome and returning the number of times that it got "tails" in a row.

A problem is my `throw()` function returns None.

```
import random

# The number that will be used to check if a function is random
tails_in_a_row = 0

# This function will check if a library provides truly random numbers
def heads_tails():

    outcomes = ("heads", "tails")
    outcome = random.choice(outcomes)

    return outcome

# The function that throws the sum and then returns it
def throw(num):
    outcome = heads_tails()

    if outcome == "tails":
        num += 1
        throw(num)
    else:
            return num

for i in range(10):
    outcome = throw(tails_in_a_row)
    print(outcome)
```

I tried to change the else statement into elif and if. I tried creating local variables inside 'throw()'.

I am expecting that when I call `return num` I will get an integer.

If I call `print(type(num))` before I call `return num` it shows that `num` is of type integer, but when I called `return type(num)` it returned type None.

Comment: If you want to keep throwing and return only when you get heads, it's better to use a `while` loop rather than recursion.

Comment: you forgot to return

Comment: `return throw(num)`

Comment: Why use a `while` loop rather than recursion as suggested above? (1) easier to code and maintain, more Pythonic and (2) there's no chance of blowing the stack and crashing the program if you have an unlucky run of more than 1k recursive calls. O(1) memory! Also, there's no need for `tails_in_a_row` to be a parameter, nor a global. Return results _up_ the call stack, not down.

Comment: Python indentation matters, here it is bad.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, find the first point in the execution where the value of a variable or subexpression is not what you expect & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `throw()` is recursive, but you don't return the value from the recursive path. You can just add `return` like this:

```py
# The function that throws the sum and then returns it
def throw(num):
    outcome = heads_tails()

    if outcome == "tails":
        num += 1
        return throw(num)

    else:
        return num
```

This fixes the problem with seeing `None` in your output, but I'm not sure that it does what you want.